# `process is not defined` bug in Vite when using Remark, Torchlight

Tags: environment-variables, vite, remarkjs

[image]Recreate the issue: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/vietan0/torchlight-vite-vanilla-js/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000g2a6ed2ypg49l%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60.7704341%252C39.2295659%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000b2a6exaaum40c%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000f2a6elbmz7tvt%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000d2a6eji57v46x%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clk979fb7000b2a6exaaum40c%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000b2a6exaaum40c%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fmain.js%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979uhl018q2a6ee9tftx7x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clk979uhl018q2a6ee9tftx7x%2522%257D%252C%2522clk979fb7000d2a6eji57v46x%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000d2a6eji57v46x%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clk979meo011h2a6e5pizx0wp%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979meo011h2a6e5pizx0wp%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clk979fb7000f2a6elbmz7tvt%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000f2a6elbmz7tvt%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clk979kv600qb2a6ej1xpr4m0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979fb7000e2a6es6aos0po%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clk979fua000bh1dw2vxh7y1a%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clk979kv600qb2a6ej1xpr4m0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I'm trying to use torchlight - a syntax highlight api with remark - a markdown tool, using [torchlight's example code](https://torchlight.dev/docs/clients/remark#adding-the-plugin) and [remark's example code](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark/tree/main#example-turning-markdown-into-html).

I ran the same code without Vite (only Node) and it worked fine, so I suspected it has something to do with Vite, so I found [this related issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973#issuecomment-787571499), but I tried the solution and nothing changed.

The bug will also go away if I don't `.use(torchlight)`, so maybe the problem is that library?